# Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed when I am trying to get the thumbnail of video file in Android

Tags: android

I am using `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` library to get `thumbnail` of video files.but i am getting problem in the line

```
byte[] image = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
```

I have tried to check the exception by surrounding  this line by try catch block.But this line is not throwing any kind of Exception but still its force closing my application.

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(filePath);

byte[] image = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();

if (image != null) {
    imgAlbum.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0,image.length));
}

retriever.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Bitmap preview = ffmmr.getFrameAtTime(2000000, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

to get frame at 2 second or whatever you want.